# Error 504 with Apache and php

Tags: php, apache, apache2

My web application works fine in development environment, but on production server gives off:

```
504 Gateway Time-out
The server didn't respond in time.
```

---

### Edit: I have traced the problem to a `session_start()` call - it never completes and ends in a 504 error above. What could cause this?

Both servers are running Linux, although of course they are not perfect clones of each other. There are many other php apps running on the same server with no issues, the production server is not overloaded in any way, and hardware wise, the production server is much better in specs than the development one. I checked out php error log and do not see anything other than

```
[22-Aug-2011 09:38:01] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_sqlite.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_sqlite.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_register_driver in Unknown on line 0
```

Which is something I see all the time even if it's working fine, and I generally don't care about this error as I'm not using sqlite.

Where else can I see what's going on and what to do to fix it?

---

### Edit:

While I could not figure out what caused the initial problem, it turned out that the problem was not occurring when using a different *web browser*. After restarting the problematic browser instance (it was Firefox, btw) the issue went away completely. I'm still puzzled how a browser could cause a server to throw 504 error.

Comment: Are you using mod_proxy, passenger or something similar?

Comment: How about the web server (Apache?) error log

Comment: you should do a google search for the error code - This problem is entirely due to slow IP communication between back-end computers, possibly including the Web server. Only the people who set up the network at the site which hosts the Web server can fix this problem. This usually means that the upstream server is down (no response to the gateway/proxy), rather than that the upstream server and the gateway/proxy do not agree on the protocol for exchanging data.

Comment: No errors in apache error log either.

Comment: I did do a search on this error code, but it does not seem normal that this server would have IP communication troubles - several similar apps are running there just fine, so I suspect some detail in my code is breaking it.

Comment: Does that happen for every script or just a few ones? Do you have mod_proxy, Nginx or similar installed?

Comment: There is no Nginx, though the web server is accessed through a load balancer. For testing purposes it is forced to a single specific server, while after completed deployment there are 2 physical web servers behind the load balancer. Not sure about mod_proxy, I see the libraries on the system, but not sure if it uses them.

Comment: Try adding `error_reporting(-1);` *before* the `session_start();` call and see if any additional errors are reported in the PHP error log.

Comment: Closing per update comments request.

Comment: We have the same problem. Did you find a reason of that issue?